Why traveling to the international space station can't be done with airplanes?
I was surprised to learn that the international space station is not at all in outer space (the space beyond the exosphere) but within the atmosphere about 400 km above sea level which is not very far from the highest maneuver altitude of probable current secret army aircraft (25-50 km above sea level) given the 10,000 km above sea level of the atmosphere and exosphere combined, hence I ask:
Is it absurd to assume that even right now or in the near future (perhaps not later than year 2100) there would be specially adjusted airplanes that could carry humans into the international space station?

You say “within the atmosphere”, but more specifically it’s the thermosphere. I would suggest looking up (1) the density of the thermosphere compared to other layers, (2) the Kármán line, and for a bonus, (3) look into “spaceplanes” which seem the closest to what you’re interested in.

If memory serves me correctly, in Stanley Kubrick's 1968 film 2001 - A Space Odyssey people did fly via Pan Am to the orbiting transfer space station on their way to the Moon. However, they they were using rocket based ships, not winged airplane suitable for the lower denser parts of the Earth's atmosphere.

Every space station successfully launched into orbit, and there have been many, has been at that altitude and has required a rocket based non-aeroplane type vehicle to get to and return from. What research have you done?

This is a basic question, but on a basic level, it's not a bad question.  I don't think it deserves to be downvoted so much.

@blobbymcblobby I don't owe you an explanation and will not further edit this simple question from a non expert to experts: I suggest you to consider to down vote andor vote to close.

@gerrit this approach of yours to access basic physics/aerospace engineering data is most appreciated ! The disrespect in public understanding of science is a major problem, the internet shows how much.

@olson tangential to the question, but possibly of interest to you is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coffin_corner_(aerodynamics) which is why the subsonic max altitude has hovered around 20 kilometers since the U2 era. SR71 blackbird style hypersonic aircraft get into a different corner where they limited by the melting point of the airframe. Agree that this is a topic that is hard to use google for as a non expert since it involves concepts like 'orbit is a speed not a height' that is not obvious.

400 km is a lot of scale heights. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale_height

@olson, this is closed primarily because you have based it on a complete fallacy that would have taken you about 2 seconds to find. The space station IS in space, as per all definitions of space. I would advise, however, that reading and understanding comments from folks trying to help is a better use of your time than lashing out.

It is indeed absurd to assume airplanes could carry humans to any space station, including the ISS.
As Fyrepenguin's comment notes, though it's true that the Earth's atmosphere extends to extremely high altitudes, above the stratosphere it's basically qualitatively unlike "the atmosphere" on the ground.  The next layer beyond the stratosphere, the mesophere, is so high up that the Wikipedia article on the exploration of the mesosphere notes

The mesosphere lies above altitude records for aircraft, while only the lowest few kilometers are accessible to balloons, for which the altitude record is 53.0 kilometres (32.9 mi). Meanwhile, the mesosphere is below the minimum altitude for orbital spacecraft due to high atmospheric drag. It has only been accessed through the use of sounding rockets, which are only capable of taking mesospheric measurements for a few minutes per mission. As a result, it is the least-understood part of the atmosphere, resulting in the humorous moniker ignorosphere. The presence of red sprites and blue jets (electrical discharges or lightning within the lower mesosphere), noctilucent clouds, and density shears within this poorly understood layer are of current scientific interest.
On February 1, 2003, Space Shuttle Columbia broke up on reentry at about 62 km (39 mi) altitude, in the lower mesosphere, killing all seven crew members.

So not only is the low-earth-orbit where the International Space Station resides so far separated from Earth that no aircraft can fly there (fyrepenguin's comment on spaceplanes notwithstanding--a spaceplane is just a spaceship that can also be an airplane sometimes, but at the ISS it is not flying the way an airplane does), its portion of the atmosphere (the thermosphere) is separated from aircraft flight by an entirely separate killer portion of the atmosphere.
Virtually everything in Why do we not fly to space with helicopters? What are the practical altitude limits? applies as well.

@olson I don't know what definition of "outer space" you're using.  The boundary section of the Wikipedia article and the Regions near the Earth section of the same article make it pretty clear that the ISS is in space.  It is also in a portion of the atmosphere, and this matters for some things, but it does not matter for your question about whether or not a plane can fly there.  Planes don't fly to that part of the atmosphere.  As my answer states.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer: The Karman Line.
Even though this is a ridiculous question, there is an enlightening answer: the Karman line. Airplanes can't fly above the Karman Line because they would no longer be "flying" using aerodynamic lift.
The point at which the atmosphere ends is arbitrary, since the density of the atmosphere smoothly decreases with altitude. Any arbitrary “line” will leave some atmosphere above. Satellites in orbit above any  arbitrary “line” will decay and de-orbit due to this residual atmosphere. The higher the “line”, the longer the period to de-orbit, even if it is measured in tens of thousands of years. Or millions.
For instance, the orbital altitude of the ISS will result in de-orbit within decades.
The advantage of Karman’s choice of a “line”: it is the altitude at which aerodynamic lift equals orbital centrifugal lift.
As the altitude of an aircraft increases, air density decreases and the airplane must travel faster to generate lift to maintain altitude. If the  altitude continues to increase, there becomes an altitude where the aircraft's aerodynamic lift is equal to the centrifugal orbital “lift”. Any higher, and the craft is no longer "flying", it is orbiting.
This altitude is about 100km, which has been designated the “Karman line”.
You can argue about the exact altitude, but the concept is useful.
The ISS is well above the Karman Line altitude, so you can’t fly there. Sorry.

I recon that you are a physicist/chemist/engineer/pilot or of a close field. I didn't have any reflective curriculum in my formal studies. To me, and many others like me, this is not a ridicules question at all. If lack of knowledge ("ignorance") is hurting you or threaten your life, perhaps it's good to ridicule it, but in such a case of making physics more accessible to the general public? I find it just nonsensical.

Minor nitpick, no downvote: I think this answer comes just short of the question, which is posed in two forms:  "Why traveling to the international space station can't be done with airplanes?" and "Is it absurd to assume that even right now or in the near future (perhaps not later than year 2100) there would be specially adjusted airplanes that could carry humans into the international space station?"  The question doesn't insist that the airplane fly, just get there; I guess the implication is "a thing that has to orbit is not an airplane?"

@ErinAnne ... Good point. Britannica's definition of airplane: " a fixed-wing heavier than air craft , propelled by a screw propeller or  jet, and supported by the dynamic reaction of the air against its wings." I don't think it is possible for such a craft to accelerate itself to orbital  speed without a rocket. At that point, it becomes, well, a rocket.
